# Publishing Azure function from VS2017 does not showing files on azure portal?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have azure function project in VS2017 and when I am publishing that project to portal,I am only getting function.json file on portal,
Is there any way to view/edit function.csx file on portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `csx` file in precompiled (Visual Studio) project. Instead, a compiled dll is created from your `cs` and `csproj` files, and that's what gets deployed. You can't see or edit the code of such project from within the portal.